# JHipster generated my project correctly but can't download maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies, jhipster

Frontend works fine,but when I try to launch backend, build failed at "Downloading: http://svnsiarti01:8081/artifactory/repo/io/github/jhipster/jhipster-dependencies/2.0.24/jhipster-dependencies-2.0.24.pom".

When i click on the link, I can't reach the website. I suppose that JHipster artifactory is down ?

Versions used: 
JHipster: 5.1.4
NPM: 6.4.1
Node.js: 8.12.0

Thanks.

Comment: a hostname without full domain (svnsiarti01) seems strange, are you running mvnw or gradlew? it looks like an internal server, don't you have some company settings somewhere?

Comment: I'm working on my company's computer from home. I know we have an internal artifactory, that could maybe enter in conflicts with the one oh JHipster I suppose ... But I didnt't do anything special and I've never had any problem before. I just generated the project and tried to launch it. I'm using maven

Comment: JHipster does not have any artifactory repo, we publish on public repositories like maven central.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so yes that was an internal server. Connected to the VPN of my company and everything worked out. That's strange because this is the first thing I tried when I first had the problem and that didn't work ... Well everything is fine now thank you.